# Does Ubuntu run level 2 have network stack configured?

Tags: linux, runlevel

I type the following command in my ubuntu 14.04 VM running on top of virtualbox:

```
$uname -a
Linux rex-VirtualBox 4.2.0-42-generic #49~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 29 20:22:11 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$runlevel 
N 2
```

Based on this article, 
http://www.pathbreak.com/blog/ubuntu-startup-init-scripts-runlevels-upstart-jobs-explained

run level 2 is explained as:

```
Does not configure network interfaces and does not export networks services
```

I am booting my ubuntu VM without any boot option modifications and i can access the internet. Why is the run level 2?

Comment: The answer from @muru is correct.  In addition, the line after the chart from the article you linked, says this, "In Ubuntu (and Debian), run levels 2 to 5 are equivalent and configured with the same set of services."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the article you link to says in huge characters before the table, that's the **traditional** mechanism. In Upstart, [runlevels 2-5 are the same](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#runlevels) in the default configuration:

> #### 4.7   Runlevels
>
> A runlevel is a single-byte name for a particular system
>   configuration. Runlevels for Debian and Ubuntu systems are generally
>   as follows:
>
> - 0 : System halt.
> - 1 : Single-User mode.
> - 2 : Graphical multi-user plus networking (DEFAULT)
> - 3 : Same as "2", but not used.
> - 4 : Same as "2", but not used.
> - 5 : Same as "2", but not used.
> - 6 : System reboot.
>
> There are also a few pseudo-runlevels:
>
> - N : The previous runlevel cannot be determined.
> - S : Alias for Single-User mode.

The runlevel is 2 because it is the default.